# Error: Entities in 'DataBase' participate in the 'FK_MSCourse_Language' relationship. 0 related 'Language' were found. 1 'Language' is expected

Tags: c#, database, linq, entity-framework, foreign-keys

Hi i try to get some Date from my Database but it wont work and i really have no Idea why.

I get following Error:

```
Error: Entities in 'DataBase' participate in the 'FK_MSCourse_Language' relationship. 0 related 'Language' were found. 1 'Language' is expected.
```

My Code:

```
var language = db.Language.Where(x => x.Designation == publicLanguage);

if (language != null)
{
  newCourse.Language = language.SingleOrDefault();
}
else
{
  newCourse.Language = db.Language.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Designation == "English");
}
```

If i do it this way it works, but i want to have it dynamically to Languages from the DataBase.

```
switch (publicLanguage)
{
  case "French":
    newCourse.Language = db.Language.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Designation == "French");
    break;
  default:
    newCourse.Language = db.Language.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Designation == "English");
    break;
}
```

Anyone knows what i am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: Is Language a nullable field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ's `Where` operation returns an IEnumerable, which can never be null, making your `if` block useless. It will always execute `newCourse.Language = language.SingleOrDefault();` no matter what.

I'm also thinking that trying to use `==` on what is most likely a string variable could be causing you some problems also. I would recommend using the `.Equals()` method instead, which will actually investigate if the strings are equal. Also, since you're just trying to grab the first one, why not just do this:

```
var language = db.Language.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Designation.Equals(publicLanguage));
```

This will grab the first one that matches that language, or return null. In such a case, then you can just have an `if` statement which will then assign English as the language if the `language` variable is, in fact, null.

Comment: Thanks for that advice, but still getting the same Error.

Comment: My Bad. Works now. Thank you